# select taking a lot of time inside union all ordering by date desc?

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have a select to get alerts.

```
select 'comments' prefix, c.foto, c.data as data, c.user, concat(k.user, ' comments your post') as logs from comentarios c 
inner join posts p on c.foto = p.id 
inner join cadastro k on c.user = k.id 
where p.user = 1 and p.user <> c.user and c.delete = 0

union all

select 'like' prefix, l.post, l.data as data, l.user, concat(k.user, ' liked your post') as logs from likes l 
inner join posts p on l.post = p.id 
inner join cadastro k on l.user = k.id 
where p.user = 1 and l.user <> p.user

order by data desc
limit 5
```

The problem is if I run the select this way it will take 2.4871 seconds.

If I remove the `select 'like'...` = 0.0024, but if I run this select apart it will take only 0.010 without the order by data desc.

any ideas why? I don't know if the problem is the union or the order by...
they are all well indexed.

[image]

Comment: The thing is, even if you have an index on `data`, the union result is a derived table (AFAIK), so it might not be possible to use it.  What about the rest of the query?  What does `EXPLAIN` show you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the explain result to my question. any ideas how to improve my query getting the same result as I have without the order by data?

Comment: `where p.user = 1 
   and c.user <> 1` seems like an improvement

Comment: If you're still struggling, consider providing SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for likes, posts, and cadastro

Comment: @Strawberry oh, it really is! I will try it and if it doesn’t improve the speed I will post the tables here. Thanks!